# How can I pull slope and intercept variables produced by the segmented package and put into a dataframe using r?

Tags: r, piecewise

Can anyone walk me through how to get the slopes and intercepts produced by the segmented package out and placed in a data frame?  This will ultimately be used to line up slopes and intercepts back to their original value.  See data (that I took from another post) below.

#load packages
    library(segmented)
    library(tidyverse)

```
#set seed and develop data
set.seed(1)
Y<-c(13,21,12,11,16,9,7,5,8,8)
X<-c(74,81,80,79,89,96,69,88,53,72)
age<-c(50.45194,54.89382,46.52569,44.84934,53.25541,60.16029,50.33870,
   51.44643,38.20279,59.76469)
dat=data.frame(Y=Y,off.set.term=log(X),age=age)

#run initial GLM
glm.fit=glm(Y~age+off.set.term,data=dat,family=poisson)
summary(glm.fit)

#run segmented glm
glm.fitted.segmented <- segmented(glm.fit, seg.Z=~age + off.set.term, psi = 
list(age = c(50,53), off.set.term = c(4.369448)))

#Get summary, slopes and intercepts
summary(glm.fitted.segmented)
slope(glm.fitted.segmented)
intercept(glm.fitted.segmented)
```

Comment: What `tidyverse` functions are you using that you think we need `library(tidyverse)` for? I don't see any.

Comment: can you give an example of your desired output?

Comment: Hi @Gregor.  I don't know if I need tidyverse.  I usually use it when I'm working in r.  I load it out of habit.

Comment: Hello @troh.  I am looking for: Varible, Slope, Intercept.  So obviously the variable will repeat, and there will be nulls in some depending on how many break points are in the model.

Comment: Your question should be as minimal as possible. You don't use `tidyverse` in your question, so the `library(tidyverse)` is just clutter. You may get answers with and without `tidyverse` packages in them.

Comment: Understood @Gregor.  Not being an r expert led to the lack of realization that the one line of code could cause confusion.  I'll keep to a minimum next time.

Comment: Just trying to encourage good habits, both in sharing minimal code and in keeping track of dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

slopes <-
  bind_rows(lapply(slope(glm.fitted.segmented), tidy), .id = "variable") %>%
  mutate(type = str_extract(.rownames, "^[a-z]+"),
         model = str_extract(.rownames, "[0-9]+$")) %>%
  select(variable, model, type, estimate = "Est.")
intercepts <-
  bind_rows(lapply(intercept(glm.fitted.segmented), tidy), .id = "variable") %>%
  mutate(type = str_extract(.rownames, "^[a-z]+"),
         model = str_extract(.rownames, "[0-9]+$")) %>%
  select(variable, model, type, estimate = "Est.")

bind_rows(slopes, intercepts) %>%
  spread(type, estimate)
```

Using the `tidy` function, you can easily pull out the data.frame for each variable then extract the model and type of unit. Bind it all together and spread the type and estimate value to end with variable, model, intercept, and slope.

Comment: Hi @troh.  This...is...awesome!  Thankyou, thank you for being so kind!

Comment: @Jordan happy to help. If the answer works for you can you please upvote and accept

Comment: Hello @troh.  In the segmented model, there is an argument to set psi which are the knots in the fit.  Is there a way I can pull those out as well in the above answer.  I tried 
    psi = str_extract(psi, "[0-9]+$") 
within the mutate command but that did not work.  If you need me to post this as a separate question, I can do that as well.

Comment: remove `$`. that symbol tells the regex to make sure the number is at the end of the string. When you remove it, it will look for any numbers.

Comment: Thanks @troh.  I think I may have to do something else.  PSI is not a part of the "slopes" function output.  The command looks like it's only taking things from that output.